# PHP echo each week's work days range

Tags: php

Im trying to get each weeks work day by range (not including saturdays and sundays), for example im using this code to show last 'May' days:

```
echo  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-3, 1, date("Y"))); 
echo ' to '; 
echo  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-2, 0, date("Y")));
echo '</br>';

$from_ = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-3, 1, date("Y")));
$top_ = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-2, 0, date("Y")));
$next_date = $from_;
while ($next_date != $top_) {
  if (date('N',strtotime($next_date)) < 6) echo $next_date."\n";
  echo '</br>';
  $next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_date.' +1 day'));
}
```

it gives me this result:

```
2015-07-01 to 2015-07-31

2015-05-01 

2015-05-04 
2015-05-05 
2015-05-06 
2015-05-07 
2015-05-08 

2015-05-11 
2015-05-12 
2015-05-13 
2015-05-14 
2015-05-15 

2015-05-18 
2015-05-19 
2015-05-20 
2015-05-21 
2015-05-22 

2015-05-25 
2015-05-26 
2015-05-27 
2015-05-28 
2015-05-29
```

I'd like to get this result:

```
2015-07-01 to 2015-07-31

2015-05-01 to 2015-05-01

2015-05-04 to 2015-05-08 

2015-05-11 to 2015-05-15 

2015-05-18 to 2015-05-22 

2015-05-25 to 2015-05-29
```

Please help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes in your code, it will help you

I add a validation if the date is saturday (5) and sunday (6), then print the first range of a week, it helps me to add +3 days ifit is saturday and +2 days if it is sunday (at the end); in the middle if the date are between a week you echo the first date and add +4 days to echo the range of a week

```
<?php
echo  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-3, 1, date("Y"))); 
echo ' to '; 
echo  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-2, 0, date("Y")));
echo '</br>';

$from_ = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-3, 1, date("Y")));
$top_ = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-2, 0, date("Y")));
$next_date = $from_;
while (strtotime($next_date) <= strtotime($top_)) 
{  
  if (date('N',strtotime($next_date)) == 5 ||date('N',strtotime($next_date)) == 6)
  {
    echo $next_date."-".$next_date;
  }
  else
  { 

    $nd=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_date.' +4 day'));
    echo $next_date."-".$nd."\n";
    $next_date=$nd;
  }
  echo '</br>';
  if (date('N',strtotime($next_date)) == 5)
  {
    $next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_date.' +3 day'));
  }
  if (date('N',strtotime($next_date)) == 6)
  {
    $next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_date.' +2 day'));
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you explain your changes, what did you change and why?

Comment: gives me this result: 2015-05-01-2015-05-01 2015-05-04-2015-05-08 .., etc thanks

Comment: @Martin I hope the explanation helps you

Comment: @simpleton if you run the code you have the dates that you want

Comment: @bicho what if I only want this result '2015-05-04 to 2015-05-08 ' instead of looping, do I need to create new question or is there a simple answer ? thanks

Comment: @simpleton you could check how many weeks the month has, and then in the bucle you could only print the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $arr = array(); $i = 0;
 while ($next_date != $top_) {
  $d=date('N',strtotime($next_date));
  if ($d < 6) $arr[$i][] = $next_date;
  else if($d==7) $i++;
  $next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_date.' +1 day'));
}
echo min($arr[0])." to ".max($arr[0]);#0,1,2
```

Try this!
Here i first collect all date's from 1-5 (day in week) in sub arrays, so i can iterate over each week. Than i get from each subarray via max()/min() the first and last day of the current week.
Can be done shorter and better, i think.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, why OPs code doesn't work and yours against does work.